# Change in ComponentMeasurements, HighlightImage, or Epilog for Version 12?

Tags: image-processing

A convenient way to check the results of `ComonentMeasurements` is to show the results using `Epilog`. However, one of these features appears to have changed behavior in Version 12.

Usually this is used for an x-ray, CT image, or Ultrasound. For example localizing the center of the active volume in an ion chamber which would be placed in this cavity:
[image: Image of Slab with Ion Chamber Hole]

For this example, i am just creating an image that shows the behavior.

Here is an example of using the `ComponentMeasurements` function to identify a simple disk in a black background and display the results of this function using `HighlightImage` and `Epilog` (which one might expect to be the same).

```
UseImage=Image[Graphics[{Black,Rectangle[{-10,-10},{10,10}],White,Disk[{0,0},1]}],ImageSize->200];
UseComp=ComponentMeasurements[UseImage,{"Centroid","Circularity","EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All,2]];
UseComp=Select[UseComp,(0.9<#[[2]]<1.&)];
Grid[{{"Version 12",SpanFromLeft},{"HighlightImage","Epilog"},{HighlightImage[UseImage
,{Red,(Disk[#[[1]],#[[3]]]&)/@UseComp}
,ImageSize->200
]
,Show[UseImage
,Epilog->{Red,(Disk[#[[1]],#[[3]]]&)/@UseComp}
,ImageSize->200
]
}}]
```

Prior to version 12, the `ComponentMeasurements` appeared to give the location of the components in units of something that matched the image.

[image: Behavior in Version 11]

In Version 12.1.1.0, the display functions have changed (larger images?) as has the behavior of `Epilog`.

[image: Behavior in Version 12]

Is there and easy way to allow a uniform behavior between `HighlightImage` and `Epilog`?

Comment: The path of least resistance is to swap out your use of `Image[Graphics[...], ImageSize->200]` for `Rasterize[Graphics[...], ImageSize->200, ImageResolution->72]`.  This restores the assumption that 1 pixel = 1 point.  Points are the native unit for `ImageSize` in the FrontEnd and are almost never equivalent to 1 pixel in 12.1+.

Comment: Thanks, you answered the question, but i asked it badly. The Image is actually an imported image - i should have made that clear in the question.

Comment: But that does work: ```Image[Import[filename],ImageResolution->72]```. Thank you!